# PHP listen for var override

Tags: php, variables, overriding, listener

Is there a way to listen to a variable being overriden...

a fictional example:

```
<?php


$user = new user_class();
function callback_foo(){
   die('Do not override this variable you are not permited...');
}
listen_var_change('user','callback_foo');

?>
```

I should hope that the code above would explain what I am trying to do, I just want to ensure that the var is constant.
I can't use the `define()` is it would not allow objects|array

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such mechanism in PHP. The closest you can get works for class members, and involves magic getters and setters. Example:

```
<?php

class Foobar {
    private $user;

    public function __construct($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function __set($key, $val) {
        if ($key === 'user') {
            die("Do not change this value, or a fluffy kitty dies.");
        }
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        if ($key === 'user') {
            return $this->user;
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty much how you'd implement read-only properties in PHP (although you probably want to throw a catchable exception rather than `die`, so that user code can recover gracefully.

Comment: I had looked at this about a year ago, but I think this would do, it's just `foobar` should be as short as possible, I will try a few things and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is not possible. If you want to have an "immutable" value, one practical solution is to hide it behind a getter function:

```
function getUser() {
    static $user;
    if (!$user) $user = new user_class();
    return $user;
}
```

Of course this is not a good practice, but it's no worse than having a `global $user`.